# Why can't I programmatically insert a 3D model into Excel from C# like in VBA?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to convert some of my old Excel VBA code to reside in a C# VSTO add-in. It's going very well except for when I tried to write the code to insert 3D models into a Worksheet.
The Shapes class for VBA has [Shapes.Add3DModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.add3dmodel), however the [Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes?view=excel-pia) class for C# does not.
Is this something Microsoft has yet to implement for C# you think? Is there any other workaround way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems Add3Model has been added to VBA model only lately and not yet been ported to VSTO / PIA  :-(
This source recommends using late-binding /InvokeMember to call the underlying COM objects method directly
https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=15830

Comment: Before you continue with c# give twin basic a try.  It will likely compile your code as is.  https://twinbasic.com/preview.html.  twinBasic is designed to a com based drop in replacement for VBA/VB6.

Comment: @freeflow I will give this a shot and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @lidqy So i don't believe Invoke.Member will work on neither 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' 14 or 15 because they simple don't contain 'Shapes.Add3DModel' (i look at it's types with reflection). What DOES contain 'Shapes.Add3DModel' is EXCEL.EXE which i found out through a HEX viewer on it.
I don't think it's possible to invoke it from c# at this time unless you have another idea from the given information. Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 0):

So there's probably other ways to do this if you spend enough time, but this solution was by far the easiest/quickest for me.
From c#:
`wb.Application.Run(Macro: "vbProjMyProject.modMyModeule.Insert3D", Arg1: sName, Arg2: sPath);`
Where Insert3D is a VBA procedure I created in that location. Downside of this is that you must also distribute & maintain a VBA add-in in addition to the VSTO until Microsoft add the Shapes.Add3DModel to c#.